# Variable, incrementation and its output

Tags: linux, bash

Here is a script:

```
VarTest01=1
VarTest02=$( printf '%s-%03d' text $VarTest01 )

while [ $VarTest01 -lt 5 ]; do
echo $VarTest02
(( VarTest01++ ))
done
```

here is its output:

```
text-001
text-001
text-001
text-001
```

My question is: why don't I get "text-001" to "text-004"? It seems $VarTest01 is being incremented but not displayed properly. What am I missing?

Comment: `var_test=0; while (( var_test < 5 )); do printf '%s-%03d\n' text $(( ++var_test ));done`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
VarTest01=1
VarTest02=$( printf '%s-%03d' text $VarTest01 )

while [ $VarTest01 -lt 5 ]; do
echo $VarTest02
(( VarTest01++ ))
done
```

You are incrementing VarTest01 but you only declare the string of VarTest02 once, so I think this would work:

```
VarTest01=1


while [ $VarTest01 -lt 5 ]; do
VarTest02=$( printf '%s-%03d' text $VarTest01 )
echo $VarTest02
(( VarTest01++ ))
done
```

Comment: It absolutely does. Thank you Jorge!

Comment: No problem, I love to help :)